# TI-82 String variable?

Tags: ti-basic

Can TI-82 store a string into a variable? I tried using "VARS" and I don't see "String" as an option. The Input command also does not take string (with double quote) as input.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it can just like the ti-84plusce.

---

Example:

```
"String"->Str0
```

Comment: How do you enter "Str0" in TI-82?

Comment: its in vars and under strings if I'm pretty sure its #7

Comment: or you could do stored in a letter like `"hello" -> W`

Comment: This is the thing. There is no "STRING" under VARS, it only goes to #6. Attempt to store string into a variable results in DATA ERR